# Sitecore XSLT rendering issues with image

Tags: xml, image, xslt, sitecore

I'm trying to output an image which has been assigned to my rendering via a template. However, when I try to output it via  I get nothing.

Here is what I have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sc="http://www.sitecore.net/sc"
  xmlns:dot="http://www.sitecore.net/dot"
  exclude-result-prefixes="dot sc">

  <!-- output directives -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <!-- parameters -->
  <xsl:param name="lang" select="'en'"/>
  <xsl:param name="id" select="''"/>
  <xsl:param name="sc_item"/>
  <xsl:param name="sc_currentitem"/>
  <xsl:param name="overrideImage"/>

  <!-- variables -->
  <xsl:variable name="home" select="$sc_item/ancestor-or-self::item[@template='site root']" />

  <!-- entry point -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$sc_item" mode="main"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--==============================================================-->
  <!-- main                                                         -->
  <!--==============================================================-->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="main">
     <p>Attempt 1:
     <xsl:value-of select="$overrideImage"  disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
     <p>Attempt 2:
     <sc:image select="$overrideImage" mw="200" /></p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So attempt 1 renders out (which actually works but not standards compliant):
    
& attempt 2 renders out nothing.

How can I get the image rendered out correctly?

Comment: Please note `<sc:image select="$overrideImageItem" mw="200" ></sc:image>` should read `<sc:image select=$overrideImage" mw="200" ></sc:image>`

Answer (score 1):

You have `overrideImageItem` instead of `overrideImage` as in attempt 1. Is this on purpose?

Comment: My bad. Copied incorrectly from the XSLT, which I simplified for the post. using $overrideImage makes no difference. It gets 0 output.

Answer (score 1):

So, I realised that I had misunderstood what was being passed by the Image item. When an Image is passed from a template it is passed as a string, with the data formatted as XML. I had to parse the string to extract the bits I was after and then I could format it as XML.

```
<xsl:variable name="mediaSrc">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($overrideImage, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="mediaAlt">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($overrideImage, 'alt=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($mediaSrc, '?mw=200')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:if test="($mediaAlt !='')">
    <xsl:attribute name="alt">
      <xsl:value-of select="$mediaAlt"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the field attribute instead if you get this through.

```
<sc:image field="ImageFieldhere"/>
```

Comment: The problem is that the image is not in a field. If is passed to the XSLT as a param, because it is specified as part of a template applied to rendering.

Answer (score 0):

What

```
<sc:image select="$overrideImage" mw="200" ></sc:image>
```

does mean? What are you trying to do?

If your intent is to evaluate the variable inside the select attribute, you should use AVT syntax:

```
<sc:image select="{$overrideImage}" mw="200" ></sc:image>
```

If you want place the variable value inside the element you should use the XSLT instruction `xsl:value`:

```
<sc:image mw="200" ><xsl:value-of select="$overrideImage"/></sc:image>
```

Comment: $overrideImage contains an object which when output to HTML appears as:
`<image mediaid="{F6A52451-9C29-4F0E-9643-B56DDEBBF080}" mediapath="/CLIENT_NAME/MicrositesFiles/Everyday First Aid/Images/Book a course" src="~/media/CLIENT_NAME/MicrositesFiles/Everyday First Aid/Images/Book a course.ashx" alt="" height="" width="" hspace="" vspace="" />`
It is this object that I want to appear as an image. The AVT syntax looks about right, but I think I've already tried it. I'll check again and confirm.

Thanks for your help, BTW.

Comment: So the AVT syntax produced no output, which I just don't understand.